# Size of UIVeiwController for iPhone is not right

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, size

I have some unusual bug.

I create some `UIViewController` in Interface builder (in side storyboard).
I launch it on "iPhone 5s", but he displayed smaller screen :

[image]

I have:

```
Size : Inferred
Resize View From NIB : Yes
```

Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project file, just add a launch image with name Default-568h@2x.png, and the problem will be solved :)

Comment: Are you kidding me :D Yes it works after hours looking at every properti of UIViewController :D Thanks